# Update data on checkbox active

Tags: php

```html
   <?php
                    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);
                   include 'database.php';
                   $pdo = Database::connect();
                   $sql = 'SELECT tl_client.first_name, tl_client.last_name, tl_dvd.title, tl_order.start_date
                   FROM tl_client, tl_dvd, tl_order
                   WHERE tl_order.dvd_id = tl_dvd.id AND tl_order.client_id = tl_client.id '; 
                    
                    
                  

                        $rented = ($_POST['rented'] == 'YES')?'YES':'NO';
                        $sql ='UPDATE tl_order SET active = 1 WHERE id = tl_order.id';

                   foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['first_name'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['last_name'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['title'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['start_date'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'   <input type="checkbox" name="rented" value="YES" />'</td>'
                            echo '</tr>';
                   }
                   Database::disconnect();
                  ?>
```

im trying to update my data using a checkbox. It needs to change the value "active" from 0 to 1" when the checkbox has been clicked.

That means that the content should be gone until later when you return it it becomes in store again. (delete but without real delete).

There's some screenshots from my databases in mysql and also the php code below:[image]

Would really appreciate some help.
Thanks

Comment: So what's the question / issue?  What isn't working and what have you tried in order to fix it?

Comment: When the checkbox is clicked, the rented value in the database should change to 1. After that the entire order should be gone from the form. (just hide)

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried, SO isn't a place for "How to's"

Comment: the code snippet AND some variants on it